# ERROR: UPDATE or DELETE statement on table

Tags: spring, jpa, foreign-keys, delete-row

In a project with Spring Boot and Spring JPA I Have two entities FunctionConfiguration and InvokeFunctionResult.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "function_configuration")
public class FunctionConfigurationEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_function_configuration")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer idFunctionConfiguration;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "invoked_function_result")
public class InvokedFunctionResultEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_invoked_result_function")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer idInvokedResultFunction;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "function_configuration_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "function_configuration_fk"), referencedColumnName = "id_function_configuration")
    private FunctionConfigurationEntity functionConfiguration;
}
```

The InvokeFunctionResult has foreign key the id of the FunctionConfiguration.
If I try to do a delete with an id of a functionConfiguration that is present in the InvokeFunctionResult:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM FunctionConfigurationEntity fce WHERE fce.idFunctionConfiguration = idFunctionConfiguration")
void deleteByFunctionConfigurationId(@Param("idFunctionConfiguration") Integer functionConfigurationId);
```

I get the following error:  Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: UPDATE or DELETE statement on table "function_configuration" violates foreign key constraint "function_configuration_fk" on table "invoked_function_result"

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try adding `CascadeType.ALL` in `@OneToOne` mapping

Comment: Like this: @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, CascadeType.ALL)